# how to import swagger in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I see a couple of articles and videos where they import Swagger. But with the new UI changes I am not able to find where to import Swagger.

In the video reference it was showing in WADL or Swagger option now I do not see Swagger option.

Has this option been removed?

Answer (score 7):

You can import swagger spec by using the Add OpenAPI specification. See the image for details.

[image: How to add swagger spec]

Comment: You can follow the tutorial from the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish

Comment: thanks when I tried to use yaml it did not parse but when i converted to json format in Swagger Editor I was able to import. So does this mean that only json format is accepted?