# Import Swagger JSON to Azure existing API Management via - Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, swagger, azure-api-management

I'm able to upload the swagger Json to Azure API management manually, It's working as expected. But I need to automate this process via azure DevOps CICD.

I need to download or fetch the swagger Json from running pod. Then I need to upload and update it in Azure API management.

I'm quite new to the process, anyone please advise me steps/tasks for the same.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish

[how to import swagger in Azure API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207710/how-to-import-swagger-in-azure-api-management)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim

https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could add task `PowerShell` or `azure PowerShell` to Import Swagger JSON to Azure API Management. This step refers to the hosted function app URL of swagger function. You can use the PowerShell command [Import-AzApiManagementApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/import-azapimanagementapi?view=azps-5.5.0). Below is a sample of command.

```
Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -SpecificationFormat "Swagger" -SpecificationPath "C:\contoso\specifications\echoapi.swagger" -Path "apis"
```

We could also refer to this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/importing-azure-function-swagger-in-azure-api-management/) for more details.